# ClientApplicationBase java class file is missing msal4j.jar and so NoSuchMethodError is coming at runtime while executing ClientCredentialGrant.java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, msal

I am using msal4j-1.13.10.jar file for certification based authentication to Sharepoint app from a web based application.

Since I have already created the CLIENT ASSERTION using PowerShell, I have used the below code to get the access token in Java.

This code is getting compiled well, but while executing the code from application, it is throwing error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> 'com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientApplicationBase$Builder
> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication$Builder.authority(java.lang.String)'

Later I found that ClientApplicationBase.class file is missing in the msal4j-1.13.10.jar file. Is this a bug in the jar file or did I miss something.

```
    IClientAssertion iClientAssertion = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromClientAssertion(CLIENT_ASSERTION);
    ConfidentialClientApplication cca;
    try {
        cca = ConfidentialClientApplication
                .builder(CLIENT_ID, iClientAssertion)
                .authority(AUTHORITY)
                .build();

        ClientCredentialParameters parameters =
                ClientCredentialParameters
                        .builder(SCOPE)
                        .build();

        IAuthenticationResult result = cca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
        System.out.println("Access token: " + result.accessToken());
        return result.accessToken();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```